# Bennett's Inequality to Bernstein's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, pade-approximation

Bennett's Inequality is stated with a rather unintuitive function,

$$
h(u) = (1+u) \log(1+u) - u
$$

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bennett%27s_inequality).  I have seen in multiple places that Bernstein's Inequality, while slightly weaker, can be obtained by bounding $h(u)$ from below,

$$
h(u) \ge \frac{ u^2 }{ 2 + \frac{2}{3} u}
$$

and plugging it back into Bennett's Inequality.  However, I can't see **where this expression comes from**.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried using a Taylor expansion for $\log(1 + u)$?

Comment: Which expression are you asking about? That of $h(u)$ or that of the lower bound for $h(u)$?

Comment: I am concerned with how to get the lower bound.

Comment: A weaker bound of $\ge\frac{u^2}{2+u}$ follows from the simple logarithmic inequality $\log(1+u)\ge\frac{2u}{2+u}$. Interesting that this fails to recover the factor $2/3$.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like a comment. Define $f(x)=(1+x) \log(1+x) - x- \frac{ x^2 }{ 2 + \frac{2}{3} x}$. You can see that $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$. However $f''(x)$ is ratio of some polynomials and it can be seen that for $x>0$, $f''(x)>0$. Hence  $f'(x)>0$ and $f(x)>0$ too.

This is an ugly way to prove it but I do not see another way for the moment.

Comment: This is the approach suggested [on page 4 of this manuscript](http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/mlss_conc.pdf).

Comment: For future people looking at this answer: I added the explicit computations in a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how the approximation
could be derived.

$\begin{align}
h(u)
&=(1+u)\log(1+u)−u\\
&=(1+u)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}u^n}{n}−u\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}u^n}{n}
+u\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}u^n}{n}−u\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}u^n}{n}
+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}u^{n+1}}{n}−u\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}u^n}{n}
+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n}u^{n}}{n-1}−u\\
&=u+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}u^n}{n}
+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n}u^{n}}{n-1}−u\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} u^n\left(\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}
+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}u^n\left(\dfrac{-1}{n}
+\dfrac{1}{n-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}u^n\left(\dfrac{1}{(n-1)n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n}u^n}{(n-1)n}\\
&= \dfrac{u^2}{2}-\dfrac{u^3}{6}+\dfrac{u^4}{12}
-\dfrac{u^5}{20}\pm ...\\
\end{align}
$

If we just look at the first two terms,

$\dfrac{u^2}{2}-\dfrac{u^3}{6}
=\dfrac{u^2}{2}(1-\dfrac{u}{3})
$,
and since
$\dfrac1{1+z}
=1-z+z^2 \pm ...
$,
$1-\dfrac{u}{3}
\sim \dfrac1{1+u/3}
$.

Therefore
$h(u)
\sim \dfrac{u^2}{2}\dfrac1{1+u/3}
= \dfrac{u^2}{2+2u/3}
$.

This shows how the approximation
could be derived.
The next step is to see
how accurate the approximation is.
Let
$h^*(u) = \dfrac{u^2}{2}\dfrac1{1+u/3} = \dfrac{u^2}{2+2u/3} $.

Expanding the approximation,

$\begin{align}
h^*(u)
&\sim \dfrac{u^2}{2}\dfrac1{1+u/3}\\
&=\dfrac{u^2}{2}(1-\dfrac{u}{3}+\dfrac{u^2}{9}
-\dfrac{u^3}{27}\pm ...)\\
&=\dfrac{u^2}{2}-\dfrac{u^3}{6}+\dfrac{u^4}{18} -\dfrac{u^5}{54}\pm ... \\
\end{align}
$

Therefore

$\begin{align}
h(u)-h^*(u)
&=(\dfrac{u^4}{12} -\dfrac{u^5}{20}\pm ...)
-(\dfrac{u^4}{18} -\dfrac{u^5}{54}\pm ...)\\
&=u^4(\dfrac{1}{12}-\dfrac{1}{18}) -u^5(\dfrac{1}{20}-\dfrac{1}{54})\pm ...\\
&=\dfrac{u^4}{36} -\dfrac{17u^5}{540}\pm ... \\ 
\end{align}
$

It certainly looks like
$h(u) > h^*(u)$.
Once you have this conjecture,
you can try to prove it.
In this case,
a proof can be developed
by looking at the successive terms
in the difference
and showing that the terms are decreasing
and alternating in sign.

Note that if we let
$h^{**}(u)
= \dfrac{u^2}{2}-\dfrac{u^3}{6}
$,
$h(u)-h^{**}(u)
=\dfrac{u^4}{12} -\dfrac{u^5}{20}\pm ...
$,
and this appears to have an error
about three times as large.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the OP is asking where $\frac{u^2}{2 + \frac23 u} $ comes from.

The answer is: $f(u) = \frac{u^2}{2 + \frac23 u}$ is the Pade $(2,1)$ approximation of $h(u)$ at $u = 0$.

As regards the proof for the Pade $(2,1)$ approximation to be a lower bound, let
$$g(u) = \ln (1 + u) - \frac{1}{1 + u}\left(u + \frac{u^2}{2 + \frac23 u}\right).$$
We have
$$g'(u) = \frac{u^3}{(1 + u)^2(3 + u)^2}.$$
Note that $g'(u) < 0$ on $(-1, 0)$, $g'(u) > 0$ on $(0, \infty)$, and $g(0) = 0$.
Thus, $g(u) \ge 0$ on $(-1, \infty)$. We are done.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by @Arash outlines the general strategy of deriving the inequality,
the explicit computation is missing.
I am providing it here in the hope that it will be helpful for future readers.

The actual computation of the derivative is highly simplified by first simplifying
the last term in the definition of
$$
  f(x)
  = (1 + x) \ln(1 + x) - x - \frac{x^2}{2 + \frac{2}{3} x}
$$
as follows:
$$
  \frac{x^2}{2 + \frac{2}{3} x}
  = \frac{3}{2} \frac{x^2}{3 + x}
  = \frac{3}{2} \frac{x \cdot (3 + x) - 3 x}{3 + x}
  = \frac{3}{2} x - \frac{9}{2} \frac{x}{x + 3}.
$$
Therefore, we see
\begin{align*}
  \require{cancel}
  f(x)
  & = (1 + x) \ln (1 + x) - \frac{5}{2} x + \frac{9}{2} \frac{x}{x + 3} , \\
  f'(x)
  & = \ln(1 + x) + 1 - \frac{5}{2} + \frac{9}{2} \frac{x+3 - x}{(x+3)^2} \\
  & = \ln(1 + x) - \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3^3}{2} (x+3)^{-2}, \\
  f''(x)
  & = \frac{1}{1 + x} - 3^3 \cdot (x+3)^{-3} \\
  & = \frac{(x+3)^3 - 27 \cdot (1 + x)}{(1 + x) (3+x)^3} \\
  & = \frac{x^{3} + 9 x^{2} + \bcancel{27 x} + \cancel{27} - \cancel{27} - \bcancel{27 x}}
           {(1 + x) (3+x)^3} \\
  & = \frac{x^{3} + 9 x^{2}}
           {(1 + x) (3+x)^3}
    \geq 0
\end{align*}
for $x \geq 0$, which is the only case we are interested in.

Since $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$, this implies $f' \geq 0$ and then $f \geq 0$
on $[0,\infty)$.